# Unable to Start Simple Transaction in SQlite

Tags: sqlite, transactions

I have started SQlite 2-days ago, and today i tried to learn Transactions in Sqlite3. But i am unable to even run the simplest ever transaction.

```
Begin;
Insert into newTable(Name,Age) values ("Adnan Ahamd KHan",24)
Insert into tbl2 (Name, FID) values ("Adnan",(Select MAx(ID) from newTable))
END Transaction;
```

Error Displayed is

```
cannot start a transaction within a transaction: Begin;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here we go,
I found the answer to my Questio. Actually i am using DBBrowser for SQlite. And upto my knowledge, you have to commit every statement in DBBrowser for SQlite.
I First created Tables, established Relationship, and without committing them all, i then tried to start that Transaction, that's why it was saying

```
cannot start a transaction within a transaction: Begin;
```

What i did, first issued a single

```
commit
```

to commit the statements which created tables, and then started Transaction. And it worked fine.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. I was running into the same problem...it would've taken me awhile to realize that it was something specific to DB Browser's implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the code and found `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` starting line and `Commit;` ending line. **I removed both (remove the first and last line which says BEGIN TRANSACTION and Commit/ END TRANSACTION) of them and it works now**.

The following failed for me:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
....
END TRANSACTION;
```

AND

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
....
Commit;
```